# LXML does not parse broken HTML : XMLSyntaxError error finding by XPath

Tags: parsing, web-scraping, lxml

I'm trying to extract a csrf token from a login page. 
I'm using as a parser the lxml library.

```py
s = requests.Session()
    login_html = etree.fromstring(
        s.get('https://www.uwkotinleuven.be/fr/login').text)
    find = etree.XPath('//*[@id="login-form-2"]/input[3]')
    print(find(login_html).value )
```

Here is the error: 
`lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 19 and head, line 46, column 24`
I'm unsure wether the error is coming from the XPath finder, or any broken HTML that is sent.

Should I change parse, or give parameters?  Is there a conventional way to parse broken HTML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a broken html problem. See if this works for you:

```
import requests
import lxml.etree as etree
from io import StringIO

s = requests.Session()
dat = s.get('https://www.uwkotinleuven.be/fr/login')

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(StringIO(dat.text), parser)

find = tree.xpath('//*[@id="login-form-2"]/input[3]')
print(find[0].attrib.values()[2])
```

Output:

> 3pKL_AsLLBE07T6S-VY8eXJ4ooK_QH5kMgajPEwKSso

Comment: Yes, that works! Is it because the HTML is broken that we go through the trouble of creating the etree.parser ?

Comment: @Falanpin - exactly.